# Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Method 'FormulR1C1' of object 'Series' failed in Powerpoint VBA when setting chart series

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am using the below POWERPOINT VBA to change the data links of every chart within a presentation to a different set of data.

This piece of code defines all the variables I use:

```
Sub AdaptData()

'This macro will change the actual references of the data series, making them pick up
'in the new sheet

'Global variables
Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim oSld As Slide
Dim oShp As Shape
Dim sOldRef1 As String
Dim sOldRef2 As String
Dim sNewRef1 As String
Dim refPathSrs As String
Dim refPathCat As String
Dim old

Dim oCht
Dim oSrs As Series
Dim oSrsCol As PowerPoint.SeriesCollection

Dim openPos As Integer
Dim closePos As Integer
Dim portRef As String
Dim SrsVals As String


'EDIT THIS TO REFLECT WHAT YOU WANT TO CHANGE ------------------
sOldRef1 = "=SERIES("    'The bit directly before the portfolio reference, i.e. [1]s1!!....
sOldRef2 = "!"           'What is directly after the portfolio reference, i.e. [1]s1!....

sToFind = "g"
sToReplace = "s"
'--------------------------------------------------------------------


'Making the change
Set myPresentation = ActivePresentation
```

I then loop through all the slides and shapes, isolate charts, then loop through all the series to isolate a specific part of the string that defines where the chart is looking for its data within the data source workbook. I make some changes to that string, then try to reassign the changed series formula. For reference, it's a copied presentation and all I want to do is change the reference to a workbook with slightly different sheet names.

See below

```
'Loop through all slides, and shapes looking for a linked chart
For Each oSld In myPresentation.Slides
    For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
        If oShp.Type = msoChart Then

            Set oCht = oShp.Chart
            Set oSrsCol = oCht.SeriesCollection

            oCht.ChartData.Activate

            'Loop through series and make replacement
            For i = 1 To oSrsCol.Count
                Set oSrs = oSrsCol(i)

                'Find the porfolio reference and extract it
                SrsVals = oSrs.FormulaR1C1
                openPos = InStr(SrsVals, sOldRef1)
                closePos = InStr(SrsVals, "!")
                portRef = Mid(SrsVals, Len(sOldRef1) + 1, closePos - Len(sOldRef1) - 1)

                'Redo the start of the reference
                refPathSrs = Replace(SrsVals, "[1]", "", 1, , vbTextCompare)
                sNewRef1 = Replace(portRef, sToFind, sToReplace, 1, , vbTextCompare)
                refPathSrs = Replace(refPathSrs, portRef, sNewRef1, 1, , vbTextCompare)

                oSrs.FormulaR1C1 = refPathSrs


            Next i

        End If
    Next oShp
Next oSld

MsgBox ("Done!")

End Sub
```

For some reason, I get the error in the title when I get to the ***oSrs.FormulaR1C1 = refPathSrs*** line.

For reference, the original series.formulaR1C1 is

```
"=SERIES(g1!R4C3,[2]g1!R5C2:R1832C2,[2]g1!R5C3:R1832C3,1)"
```

And the value of refPathSrs that I'm trying to put back in is:

```
"=SERIES(s1!R4C3,s1!R5C2:R1832C2,s1!R5C3:R1832C3,1)"
```

I have googled but nothing seems to address this issue, apart from this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/run-time-error-2147467259-80004005. The data source workbook is not protected in any way, so this cannot be the case.

Comment: Would be useful to Debug.Print the "old" and "new" formulas so you (and we) could compare a couple of examples

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about this feature! I've added Debug.Print lines after each time a string is defined or changed, but it confirms what I wrote above, that the value of _refPathSrs_ that I'm trying to use as the new series formula is valid. Incidentally, if I wanted to show you the output of the Debug.Print box, how would I do this on here?